# Compiled iOS Phonegap app does not get any coordinates after startup

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I have a problem: In the PhoneGap app running on iOS everything works fine (InAppBrowser opens, coordinates are retrieved etc.), but as soon as I compile the app and install in the testfligh or directly from the store, the coordinates are only retrieved when I use the Minimize App (App overview, by pressing the Home button twice). This is the same with the InAppBrowser.
Does anyone have an idea how to debug or even resolve?

Thanks in advance.
Hendrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add gap: to your CSP meta tag, or remove the whole CSP if you are not really using it